# trying to call the package RoAuth but getting an error no package called RCurl?

Tags: r, rcurl, roauth

: library(ROAuth) after installing but receiving Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROAuth’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package called ‘RCurl’

Comment: If you got an error message saying a package isn't installed, you should install it. Did you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the required package:

```
install.packages("RCurl")
```